# AJAX callback not handling data properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP script that I'm calling with the `.post()` function in jQuery. If everything goes well, it outputs "WIN", otherwise it outputs whatever database errors or whatever else it gets.

```
$.post("myscript.php", {key: "value"}, function(data) {
   if(data=="WIN") {
      // the stuff that I want it to do that it won't do
   } else {
      alert(data);
   }
});
```

When it runs however, I get "WIN" in a JS alert, and the stuff that I want it to do doesn't happen. Since "WIN" shows up in the alert, the PHP script is clearly outputting what I had expected. I had even made sure to set the `Content-Type` of the PHP script to `text/plain`, so why doesn't `data=="WIN"`. Why does my WIN FAIL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked for whitespace? Any whitespace before or after `echo "WIN"` will affect the output, also, check for whitespace before and after your `<?php` tags.

Comment: Hmm good point. I think I've gotten rid of all the whitespace before the "WIN", but my IDE seems to be adding a newline at the end of the file every time I save. Maybe I should filter out the whitespace in javascript.

Comment: `data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');` trimmed things up real good.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I just realized jQuery had a `.trim()` function. I'll use that.

Comment: You could also just avoid closing your php files with `?>` leave it open, works fine ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely trying to access the returned data from 'data' directly. Try

```
 alert(data.d);
```

I think that you will find that the returned data is in a property. If I remember correctly, that property's name is 'd'. Use the FireFox plugin [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to view the returned data. It is very helpful for AJAX debugging.

Good Luck!

Comment: If the returned data is plain text, then `data` should be the exact output of the file from what I understand. I think the whole properties thing mostly applies to JSON data.